# Using ImageDataGenerator.fit for arguments like 'featurewise_std_standardization', 'zca_whitening

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, data-science

I want to use ImageDataGenerator.fit for arguments like 'featurewise_std_standardization', 'zca_whitening on a directory of images.

I found some solutions online for converting images into NumPy arrays, however, want to find out a simpler method so that I can use flow_from_directory as well for new data labels, etc. The code looks something like this.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                               zoom_range = 0.2,
                               horizontal_flip = True, zca_whitening=True)



**This is where I want to fit the data something like this,**

train_datagen.fit('data/train')

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('data/train',
                                             target_size = (64, 64),
                                             batch_size = 32,
                                             class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('data/test',
                                        target_size = (64, 64),
                                        batch_size = 32,
                                        class_mode = 'binary')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround using cv2,

```
img = cv2.imread(i, -1)
img = cv2.resize(img, (64, 64))
img = np.array(img, dtype="float")
```

This creates a numpy array for me which I can then fit into datagen

```
datagen.fit(img)
```